# Validar si un correo tiene @ o un espacio vacio en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Me tira error porque el id email es null
el error es el siguiente : " index.html?email=:31 Uncaught TypeError: email1.includes is not a function
at enviarForm (index.html?email=:31)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html?email=:31)
"

```
<script>
 let email1 = document.getElementsByName("email")
console.log(email1)

function enviarForm(){
if(email1.includes("@") ){
    alert("Email ingresado correctamente");
} else if (email.includes(" ") ) {
    alert("No escribas el correo con espacios vacios")
} 
else {
    alert("Revisa que no te falte el @")
}
} 
</script>
<form action="" class="form">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email adress..." >
 <input type="submit" value="Notify Me" class="button" onclick="enviarForm()"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hola, Arturo. Recuerda que el código se comparte como texto. Así mismo, incluye en tus preguntas el error completo (para que sepamos un poco más sobre lo que sucede). Y sobre tu error, posiblemente quieras acceder al `.value` del elemento. email1 es una referencia a ese nodo en el DOM, así que no va a tener método `includes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que el metodo `getElementById` devuelve un objeto de nodo del DOM que representa al nodo en si y estas empleando un metodo que no pertece al prototipo.

En resumen `document.getElementById("email").includes("foo")` no existe, por lo que tendras un error.

El metodo `includes` pertence solo al prototipo de array y string.

Para obtener el valor de un nodo como el imput tienes que utilizar la propiedad `.value` del objeto/elemnto:

```
let foo = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

La variable `foo` ahora es un string con el cual si puedes utilizar el metodo `includes`.

Despues de eso, para ayudarte con la pregunta, te recomiendo utilizar una expresión regular para evaluar el string:

```js
let exp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

let reg = new RegExp(exp, "i")

let email = "myemail@gmail.com"

console.log(reg.test(email))

email = "myemail gmail.com"

console.log(reg.test(email))

email = "myemail@gmail|com"

console.log(reg.test(email))
```

Es mucho mejor utilizar expresiones regulares para validar datos ya que puedes evadir muchos fallos con una logica mas simple.

#### Implementando el codigo basado en tu ejemplo:

```js
let email = document.querySelector("#email"),
send = document.querySelector("#send");

const sendEmail = () => {
  let exp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
  let reg = new RegExp(exp, "i")
  let value = email.value;
  if (!reg.test(value)) return alert("Parece que ingresaste un email no valido.") 
  alert("Enviado")
}

send.addEventListener("click", sendEmail);
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email">
<button id="send" >Enviar</button>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Aca te dejo algunos links utiles:

- [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes)
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)
- [Expresiones regulares (expresiones)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [HTML DOM Element Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema radica en que tu variable email1 es un objeto/elemento HTML el cual carece de la funcion includes.

```
 let email1 = document.getElementsByName("email")
```

Para validar si contiene o no un @ primero debes acceder al texto de este

```
let email1 = document.getElementsByName("email")

function enviarForm(){
if(email1.value.includes("@") ){
    alert("Email ingresado correctamente");
} else if (email.includes(" ") ) {
    alert("No escribas el correo con espacios vacios")
} 
else {
    alert("Revisa que no te falte el @")
}
}
```

Aunque cinseramente considero que es mejor validar con una expresion regular

```
/^\w+([.+-]?\w+)*@[a-z0-9]+([-_]{1,2})?([a-z]*)(\.[a-z]{2,15})+$/.test(email1.value)
```